# How to use joehewitt scrollability?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

Can anyone help me out in implementing joehewitt's scrollability plugin.(https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability.git)
I am trying to develop a mobile web app!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “This project is a WORK-IN-PROGRESS and is not yet ready to use. Stay tuned! Documentation will be written when the library is ready.” https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/blob/master/README.md

Comment: could you please edit you question and add code/errors/what you have tried/etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so,

1)Include the javascript file and the css file (its in the static folder)

2) Head to http://scrollability.com/
and following the structure create the two divs:

```
<div id="overflow">
  <div id="scrollysection">
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS

```
#overflow
    overflow:hidden
    position:absolute
    top:0px
    left:0px
    width:100%
    height:100%

#scrollysection
position:absolute
top:0px
left:0px
```

3)Then you need to apply the fix here: https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/issues/29

> To get the code running just comment out or remove all of the exports
>   stuff (lines 77-84). Then on line 94 where require is mentioned, just
>   pull the two lines of code out of that ready function and comment the
>   ready function out.

Thats what I did and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code of: http://www.uponahill.com/ It is done by Joe Hewitt and uses scrollability.